# odbcinst: symbol lookup error: odbcinst: undefined symbol: iniOpen error installing msodbcsql17

Tags: odbc

Ubuntu server 20.04.
After updating all packets, msodbcsql17 stopped working.

I've purged it and then tried to reinstall and i get an error in post-install process.

The error is

```
odbcinst: symbol lookup error: odbcinst: undefined symbol: iniOpen
```

The unixodbc package is installed and it seems ok

```
root@zerfasv005:/home/utente1# odbcinst

**********************************************
* unixODBC - odbcinst                        *
**********************************************
*                                            *
* Purpose:                                   *
*                                            *
*      An ODBC Installer and Uninstaller.    *
*      Updates system files, and             *
*      increases/decreases usage counts but  *
*      does not actually copy or remove any  *
*      files.                                *
*                                            *
* Syntax:                                    *
*                                            *
*      odbcinst Action Object Options        *
*                                            *
* Action:                                    *
*                                            *
*      -i         install                    *
*      -u         uninstall                  *
*      -q         query                      *
*      -j         print config info          *
*      -c         call SQLCreateDataSource   *
*      -m         call SQLManageDataSources  *
*      --version  version                    *
*                                            *
* Object:                                    *
*                                            *
*      -d driver                             *
*      -s data source                        *
*                                            *
* Options:                                   *
*                                            *
*      -f file name of template.ini follows  *
*         this (valid for -i)                *
*      -r get template.ini from stdin, not   *
*         a template file                    *
*      -n Driver or Data Source Name follows *
*      -v turn verbose off (no info, warning *
*         or error msgs)                     *
*      -l system dsn                         *
*      -h user dsn                           *
*                                            *
* Returns:                                   *
*                                            *
*      0   Success                           *
*     !0   Failed                            *
*                                            *
* Please visit;                              *
*                                            *
*      http://www.unixodbc.org               *
*      pharvey@codebydesign.com              *
**********************************************
```

I've tried even to reinstall unixodbc but still get the same error